# ios swift AWS cognito and Facebook Authentication

Tags: ios, swift, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, facebook-sdk-4.0

I am trying to use Facebook credentials to login on to AWS. I have set up a federate identity using Facebook as my social identity provider on Amazon Cognito but for some reason it does not authenticate. The Docs on Amazon are not up to date so I am not sure what to do.

Below is some swift code from the ios app:

```
let token = FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken().tokenString

    let provider = MyProvider(tokens: [AWSIdentityProviderFacebook: token])


    let credentialsProvider = AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider(regionType: region, identityPoolId: poolId, identityProviderManager: provider)


    let configuration = AWSServiceConfiguration(region: region, credentialsProvider:credentialsProvider)

    AWSServiceManager.defaultServiceManager().defaultServiceConfiguration = configuration

    let id = credentialsProvider.getIdentityId()
```

Here is the MyProvider class:

```
import Foundation
import AWSCognitoIdentityProvider

class MyProvider:NSObject, AWSIdentityProviderManager{
     var tokens : [NSString : NSString]?
     init(tokens: [NSString : NSString]) 
     {
         self.tokens = tokens
     }
    @objc func logins() -> AWSTask {

        return AWSTask(result: tokens)
    }
}
```

I am able to get a token from Facebook and login but when I pass this token to Cognito I get an error like "NotAuthorizedException" "Token is not from a supported provider of this identity pool." The pool ID and region I pass to AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider match to the ones on Amazon Cognito, the method I defined in MyProvider gets called. If anyone has got it to work please share what you have did that got it working. I will appreciate any advice and help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved my problem somehow. All I did was deleted my identity pool and Facebook app and created new ones. It is now working fine.

Answer (score 1):

I am trying to do the facebook authentification and cognito login. I did almost same code as you did. The bellow is my code.

```
@IBAction func SigninWithFaceBook(_ sender: Any) {
    let loginManager: FBSDKLoginManager = FBSDKLoginManager()
    loginManager.logIn(withReadPermissions: ["public_profile", "email", "user_birthday", "user_gender"], from: self) { (result, error) in
        if error != nil {
             print("error")
        } else if (result?.isCancelled)! {
            print("Cancelled")
        } else {
            let loginResult: FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult = result!
            if loginResult.grantedPermissions != nil {
                if loginResult.grantedPermissions.contains("email") {
                    if FBSDKAccessToken.current() != nil {
                        let tokenString = FBSDKAccessToken.current().tokenString
                        print("FBSDKAccessToken.current() \(FBSDKAccessToken.current()) string \(String(describing: tokenString)) )")
                        FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: ["fields": "id, name, email, gender, birthday "]).start(completionHandler: { (connection, result, error) -> Void in
                            if error == nil {
                                let json = result as! [String : Any]
                                 print("FBSDKGraphRequest \(json)")
                                let email = json["email"] as! String
                                let id = json["id"] as! String
                                let name = json["name"] as! String
                                let gender = json["gender"] as! String
                                let birthdate = json["birthday"] as! String
                                print("facebook login suceseeded email \(email)) id \(id) id \(name) gender \(gender) birthData \(birthdate)  ")

                            //// Sync Cognito UserPool for facebook login //////////////////
                                let customcedentialProvider = CustomIdentityProvider(tokens: ["graph.facebook.com" : tokenString!])
                                let credentialsProvider = AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider(regionType: CognitoIdentityUserPoolRegion,
                                                                                        identityPoolId: CognitoFederatedIdentityUserPoolID,
                                                                                        unauthRoleArn: CognitoFedratedIAMRoleUnauthARN,
                                                                                        authRoleArn: CognitoFedratedIAMRoleAuthARN,
                                                                                        identityProviderManager: customcedentialProvider)
                                let configuration = AWSServiceConfiguration(region:CognitoIdentityUserPoolRegion, credentialsProvider:credentialsProvider)
                                AWSServiceManager.default().defaultServiceConfiguration = configuration
                                credentialsProvider.getIdentityId()
                                print("credentialsProvider.getIdentityId() \(credentialsProvider.getIdentityId())")

                                self.navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: true)
                                self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
                                print("didCompleteFBLogin  ~~~~~ No Error ----- and dismiss")

                            }else{
                                print("FBSDKGraphRequest error")
                            }
                        })
                    } else {
                        print("Token is nil")
                    }
                    loginManager.logOut()
                } else {
                    print("It can not get user email from this Facebook user")
                }
            } else {
                print("Permission is not granted")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am not sure whether Cognito logoin worked or not. 
Print our of "credentialsProvider.getIdentityId()" was completed as following but no user pool was registered in Cognito user in the Cognito Federated Identity pool for FederatedAppAuthRole.

credentialsProvider.getIdentityId()  AWSTask: 0x1c5e78d00; completed = YES; cancelled = NO; faulted = NO; result = ap-northeast-1:2fd1e4aa-97f4-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX

Please let me know of your advice.

Answer (score 0):

The key in your logins map should be **graph.facebook.com**. Try using `AWSCognitoLoginProviderKey.Facebook.rawValue` instead of `AWSIdentityProviderFacebook`

Comment: AWSCognitoLoginProviderKey.Facebook.rawValue is deprecated

Comment: Hi, Have you implemented facebook login through AWS . I struggling to implement this please help me to do this.

Comment: The sheer amount of code and setup required to use Cognito is mind blowing. I found Firebase to be much smarter and easier to integrate to swift.